# Nested Structures declaration and how to access them

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am having trouble using a pointer to a nested structure and using those variables in those structures in my member functions of my class.

I have these variables declared. Let me know if they are declared right in relation to the nesting of the structures.

```
 const int MAX_ACCOUNT_COUNTRY = 36;
    const int MAX_ACCOUNT_CITY = 50;
    const int MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME = 10;
    const int MAX_NUMBER = 16;
    const int MAX_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS = 25;
    const int MAX_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 50;
    const int MAX_OFFICE_HOURS = 20;
    const int businessID = 0;
    const int residentalID = 1;

    typedef char accountCountry[MAX_ACCOUNT_COUNTRY + 1];
    typedef char accountCity[MAX_ACCOUNT_CITY + 1];
    typedef char accountName[MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 1];
    typedef char phoneNumberFormat[MAX_NUMBER + 1];
    typedef char accountAddress[MAX_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS + 1];
    typedef char accountEmail[MAX_ACCOUNT_EMAIL + 1];
    typedef char officeHours[MAX_OFFICE_HOURS + 1];

    typedef phoneBook * phonebookPtr;

public:
    Phonebook(const int numPages);
    ~Phonebook();
    void addAccount(const int);
    void removeAccount(const int);
    void editAccount(const int);
    void viewPhonebook();

private:
    struct phoneBook{
        struct businessAccountEntry
        {
            const int businessID;
            accountCountry businessCountry;
            accountCity businessCity;
            accountName businessName;
            accountName accountHolder;
            accountAddress businessAddress;
            accountAddress mailingAddress;
            phoneNumberFormat phoneNumber;
            phoneNumberFormat faxNumber;
            accountEmail businessEmail;
            officeHours businessOfficeHours;
        };

        struct residentialAccountEntry
        {
            const int residentialID;
            accountName residentName;
            accountAddress mailingAddress;
            phoneNumberFormat phoneNumber;
        };
    };

    phonebookPtr thePhonebook;

    int counterID = 0;

    Phonebook();
    Phonebook(Phonebook &);
};
```

How do I access the variables inside the structure `businessAccountEntry` in my class for my member functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give them a name like

```
struct phoneBook{
    struct businessAccountEntry
    {
        const int businessID;
        accountCountry businessCountry;
        accountCity businessCity;
        accountName businessName;
        accountName accountHolder;
        accountAddress businessAddress;
        accountAddress mailingAddress;
        phoneNumberFormat phoneNumber;
        phoneNumberFormat faxNumber;
        accountEmail businessEmail;
        officeHours businessOfficeHours;
    } businessAccount;

    struct residentialAccountEntry
    {
        const int residentialID;
        accountName residentName;
        accountAddress mailingAddress;
        phoneNumberFormat phoneNumber;
    } residentialAccount;
};
```

and use it : `thePhonebook->residentialAccount.residentialID`

Comment: Thank you, was never taught that in any of my classes so far as a CS major and not in any of the books that I have.

Comment: how would I use `phonebookPtr->residentialAccount.residentialID` and assign it to a specific index in an array of structures? Would I need to create a temporary variable to hold it then store it?

Comment: Maybe you should use std::vector<phoneBook> instead of a ptr for thePhonebook

Comment: I don't know much about vectors but is there a way to do it with an array of structures or no? @Jerome